# UWP Custom control binding not working in either direction

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, uwp

I'm working on a custom number picker control in UWP and I'm trying to bind a view model to its SelectedValue property. Presently, even with two way binding and the update trigger set to `PropertyChanged`, my binding does not work in either direction. For now I've worked around it using event handlers, but I'd like to break this control out into a library for custom controls for our company and have it be usable out of the box. Following is my control code and the basic code of the page I'm using the control in:

NumberPicker.xaml:

```
<ItemsControl
    x:Class="UWPApp.Scorekeeper.NumberPicker"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UWPApp.Scorekeeper"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vms="using:UWPApp.Scorekeeper.Models.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Name="Select" 
    Loaded="Select_Loaded" 
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ItemsCollection}"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:NumberItem">
            <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="115">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Value}"></TextBlock>
            </Viewbox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid BorderThickness="4" BorderBrush="Black">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Rectangle Opacity=".5">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=".5,0" EndPoint=".5,1">
                                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Black"/>
                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <ScrollViewer Grid.RowSpan="3" ViewChanged="Select_ViewChanged" VerticalSnapPointsType="Mandatory" VerticalSnapPointsAlignment="Center" x:Name="MinutesSelect" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalScrollMode="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                        <ItemsPresenter></ItemsPresenter>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                    <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Opacity=".5">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=".5,1" EndPoint=".5,0">
                                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Black"/>
                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            </StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

NumberPicker.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using UWPApp.Scorekeeper.Models.ViewModels;
using UWPApp.Scorekeeper.Toolbox;


namespace UWPApp.Scorekeeper
{
    public class NumberItem
{
    public NumberItem(int? value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
    public int? Value { get; set; }
}

public sealed partial class NumberPicker : ItemsControl
{


    public event SelectionChangedEventHandler SelectionChanged;

    public int RangeBottom { get; set; }

    public int RangeTop { get; set; }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedValue", typeof(int?), typeof(NumberPicker), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSelectedValueChanged)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectionChangedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectionChanged", typeof(SelectionChangedEventHandler), typeof(NumberPicker), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    private static void OnSelectedValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var picker = d as NumberPicker;
        picker.SelectionChanged?.Invoke(picker, new SelectionChangedEventArgs(new List<object> { e.OldValue }, new List<object> { e.NewValue }));
        return;
    }

    public int? SelectedValue { get { return (int?)GetValue(SelectedValueProperty); } set { SetValue(SelectedValueProperty, value); } }

    public ObservableCollection<NumberItem> ItemsCollection { get; set; }

    public NumberPicker()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        ItemsCollection = new ObservableCollection<NumberItem>();
    }

    private void Select_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.IsIntermediate)
        {
            var scroll = sender as ScrollViewer;
            var position = scroll.VerticalOffset;
            var value = Math.Floor(position / 115d);
            SelectedValue = ((int)value);
        }
    }

    private void Select_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var count = RangeTop - RangeBottom + 1;
        var items = Enumerable.Range(RangeBottom, count).Select(m => new NumberItem(m)).ToList();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            ItemsCollection.Add(item);
        }
        ItemsCollection.Insert(0, new NumberItem(null));
        ItemsCollection.Add(new NumberItem(null));
        var period = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
        Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPoolTimer.CreateTimer(async (source) =>
        {
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                var scroll = Select.FindFirstChild<ScrollViewer>();
                if (SelectedValue != null)
                {
                    var position = SelectedValue * 115d + 81.5;
                    scroll.ChangeView(null, position, null, true);
                }
            });
        }, period);
    }
}
}
```

Page.xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="UWPApp.Scorekeeper.SelectPenaltyTime"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UWPApp.Scorekeeper"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vms="using:UWPApp.Scorekeeper.Models.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Name="PageElement"
    Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="600"
    d:DesignWidth="1024">

    <ContentPresenter x:Name="MainContent" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="110*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="43*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="47*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <local:NumberPicker Margin="100,0,750,0" RangeBottom="0" RangeTop="20" SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=PageElement,Path=ViewModel.Minutes,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></local:NumberPicker>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPresenter>
</Page>
```

Page.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using UWPApp.Scorekeeper.Models.TransportClasses;
using UWPApp.Scorekeeper.Models.ViewModels;

namespace UWPApp.Scorekeeper
{
    public sealed partial class SelectPenaltyTime : Page
    {
        public GameStateModel StateModel { get; set; }

        public AddPenalty_FVM ViewModel { get; set; }

        public SelectPenaltyTime()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            var message = e.Parameter as PenaltyMessage;
            StateModel = message.StateModel;
            ViewModel = message.ViewModel;
        }

        private void NumberPicker_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var picker = sender as NumberPicker;
            picker.SelectedValue = ViewModel.Minutes;
        }

        private void NumberPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var picker = sender as NumberPicker;
            ViewModel.Minutes = picker.SelectedValue;
        }
    }
}
```

AddPenalty_FVM:

```
public class AddPenalty_FVM
    {
        public int? Minutes { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: where is your ViewModel, does it implement INotifyProperty interface?

Comment: It shouldn't need to, right? Since the value is only loading from it when the page loads? That is, nothing but the selector is setting the viewmodel property.

Comment: It seems this is all a limitation of `Binding` anyway, as it works correctly with `x:Bind`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a bit of investigating and here's what I discovered:

- If `NumberPicker` derives from `ItemsControl`, the two-way binding will not work. If it instead derived from `UserControl`, then the two-way binding will work.
- It looks as though you originally created `NumberPicker` as a `UserControl` (via right click project > Add > New Item > User Control), but then changed the base class from `UserControl` to `ItemsControl`. While this is not necessarily a bad thing to do, in this case it seems to break two-way bindings (ultimately because of the `Application.LoadComponent()` call it does inside `InitializeComponent()` in the constructor). Instead you should create a *Templated Control*, which works by creating a .cs code file and the XAML for the `DefaultStyle` of the control will go into Themes/Generic.xaml. If you organize your control in this way, the two-way binding should work.

There are also a couple of things I'd like to point out regarding the view model:

- Your view model class does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` which means that changes to the view model's properties will not propagate to the `NumberPicker`. If you want this to happen, the source of the binding (the view model) must support property change events through the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, or the property must be a `DependencyProperty`.
- If you do implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, then you also need to update your `NumberPicker` class to update the view in response to changes in the `SelectedValue` property, which you are not currently doing. You're only raising the `SelectionChanged` event on the control in this situation, you need to scroll the `ScrollViewer` to match the new value.

Comment: I'm aware of that, the value of Minutes does not change outside of this selector, so it didn't seem necessary to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. I would use OneWayToSource... If UWP had it.

Comment: But yes, using `Binding` the property does not update, but with `x:Bind` it does.

Comment: Oh OK, I just thought you wanted two way binding mechanics since you specified `Mode=TwoWay` in the binding.

Comment: Yeah, appreciated c: Not sure why they got rid of `OneWayToSource`, but we make do. I have updated my code now so that it's compatible with actual two way binding, but I didn't plan on using it myself.